# passing doctrine entity manager as a parameter to a generic class

Tags: php, function, symfony, parameters, doctrine

I have a generic PHP class I'm using to contain functions/methods I use in multiple Symfony Controllers. In order to use the entity manager, I'm passing it like so:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $dbf = new DBFunctions($em);
     $result = $dbf->doSomething();
  }
}
```

My generic class looks like this:

```
class DBFunctions
{
  private $em;
  public function __construct($em1)
  {
    $em = $em1;
    var_dump($em1);
  }

  public function doSomething(){
      $query = $em->createQuery(<my query>);
      return $query->getResult();
  }
}
```

The problem is when I run the function I get the following error:

```
 Call to a member function createQuery() on a non-object
```

BUT my var_dump shows this (and a ton more):

```
object(EntityManager514e73398155c_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[236]
private 'delegate' => 
object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[231]
```

I'm sure its an object, so I'm lost as to what to do.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't have one variable pass from one method to another like that. If you do `var_dump($em)` in your `doSomething()` method, you will see that it returns `NULL`. Either pass it as a parameter to that method or set `$this->em` in your constructor.